# Like php session, js/jquery session is there?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session

In PHP I can store values in a session I can get until it is destroyed / unset,
Is this possible in jQuery or JS, too?

I need to store client side values to retrieve them in another page.

Comment: Do you back up your client code with a server? Please describe the setup of "another page" and "retrieving".

Comment: You cannot store values in session, you use a cookie to store. jquery also has cookie plugin using which you can store your values

Comment: I have created a comment system (php - jQ) and for example I use jQ cookies to mantain the admin panel opened (even at page reload or change) and even the Admin - logged in. !

Comment: For now is in Croatian but look at the codes: A how to: [JQ COOKIES](http://roko.x10.mx/cookie/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use cookies or if you need to store lots of data and don't need compatibility with non-state-of-the-art browsers you could also use HTML5 localStorage.

Comment: Html5 local storage... what about non-html-5 browsers? Can they handle this?

Comment: As I said, it's only supported by recent browsers.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like a session variable directly available in javascript but there are definitely some alternatives to achieve this type of behavior. Two I can think of:

#### Javascript cookies

As demonstrated on [this page](http://techpatterns.com/downloads/javascript_cookies.php) you can create and retrieve cookies in javascript.

#### AJAX

You could use AJAX requests to set and retrieve your session variables from a php file. If you're not familiar with AJAX you can find some decent examples [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost.shtml) for the classic javascript approach or in case of jQuery [in the jQuery .ajax() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). This method is probably more reliable because it doesn't depend on the client allowing cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JStorage  plugin for this ,[JStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) , jStorage makes use of HTML5 local storage where available and userData behavior in Internet Explorer older versions. Webkit SQLite is not supported.Current availability: jStorage supports all major browsers - Internet Explorer 6+, Firefox 2+, Safari 4+, Chrome 4+, Opera 10.50+ , (under 1kB when gzipped)!